# Customize Email body of send approval message in power automate

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, power-automate, power-platform

I have added action to send approval in power automate. But in email I can see created by name as who has last updated the flow. Is there any way we can remove created by or customize the approval email body or any other way I can handle this? I need only requested by name here(who has created a list item). Here is the image for reference,

[image]

Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you found your solution. However, my take on your question is as the attached.
1.Ensure you select "Custom Responses-..." for your approval type.
2.Feel free to customized your own email body in the "details" section.

[This is how you do it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHxAt.png)

[The customized email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIXB2.png)

Hope this solution solves your issues.